# Regex to find the last "}" on last line

Tags: regex

I am having trouble writing a regex for the last "}" in the last line in a file.

For example, if this is the file:

```
    /*
           blas
     */
    
    import bla;
    
    
public class bla {
...
    
    public void bla (blas){
    ...
    }

...
} //this is the "}"
```

Can anyone help?

It's preferable if the solution doesn't rely on indentation or lack of additional comments at the end (I think it's fair to assume that even if there are comments at the end then they don't contain "}"), but right now I'm prepared to take anything.

The best I could do was: `^}$` but that relies on proper indentation.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: which regex flavor ? `(}).*\Z` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for multi-line modifiers, just use this `}(?=[^}]*$)`
This would find the last `}` in the file.

If you want to force a find only on the last line it's `(?m)^.*(}).*\z`

or, if the last *visible* line it's `(?m)^.*(}).*\s*\z`

Answer (score 0):

Simple as halwa!

use this:

```
}.*?$
```

Example here: https://regex101.com/r/oM3tW3/1

If you want to return the match, use:

```
(}).*?$
```